# Parameter passing in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to make some questions about asp.net mvc.Actually,i am not familiar with web developing.my questions are i have two controllers,one is login and another one is 
profile.After login,i want to call profile.so,i use this way,

return RedirectToAction("DiaplayProfile","Profile",new { personID = Person.personID});

my problem is parameter that i passed are shown i URL.i don't want to show.In web developing,if we use post method to send data,parameters are not shown in url,is it correct?for me,i need to pass parameter ,but,i don't want to show at url.
How i use in post method in MVC RedirectToAction?i also tested with TempData 
to pass data,but,it's gone after if i make refresh.how i hanlde this?And also,
can i use [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] for solve this problem?

guide me right ways, please.

Regards
Chong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a post as part of a redirect; a redirect must be a get request since you're simply passing the browser the URL to which to redirect.  In MVC, having the id as part of the URL is actually considered to be a good thing.  I would embrace it.  Rather than having the parameter be `personID`, I would use `id` so that the default routing can be used.  Eventually I'd want to end up with a URL that looks like:

```
http://example.com/profile/display/1345
```

where 1345 is the `id` of the person in question.  If you use default routing, that would mean that you have a `ProfileController` with a `Display` method that takes a single `id` parameter (of type `int`).  You would redirect to it using:

```
return RedirectToAction( "display", "profile", new { id = 1345 } );
```

BTW, you can't use the `AcceptVerbs` attribute to control how a redirect is made, only to control what HTTP verbs the action will respond to.  In this case, I think you really do want to accept a `GET` and I think you really do want to have the id in the URL.

Comment: thanks for answer,so,now,my thinking is,first,i create static class and i will insert data to those before calling to profile controller.this is the way i don't need to pass any data and i can reuse from any controller.can i use this way?is it the right way to avoid showing parameter at url?guide me please. :)

Comment: @Chong - if you have extra data that you need to keep beyond the id, you can use the session or persist it to the db (and read it back) on the next request.  There's no need to create a static class to mimic the session object.  If it's just the id, leave it in the URL.

Comment: ok tvanfosson,our problem is we need to pass ID or nric but we don't want to show it at url cause of our customer policy,if we pass those parameter in RedirectToAction it will show at url,correct?can i hide this?i think we need to use session or read and back from db.